Present Value Error on SQL calculation different From Excel Calculation
I created a function on SQL to calculate Present Value
SET @pv = -(@pmt * (1 + @rate * @type) * (1 - POWER(1 + @rate, -@nper)) / @rate + @fv / POWER(1 + @rate, @nper))

and I passed this values to It
SET @pv = -(52843.00 * (1 + 0.00631333 * 1) * (1 - POWER(1 + 0.00631333, -240.5689440)) / 0.00631333 + 0 / POWER(1 + 0.00631333, 240.5689440))

and it resulted to -6569663.24 while on excel I got -6569663.04
What am I doing wrong
I tried to get the same value as the value from the excel

Seems like a rounding difference. Different tools can have different rounding defaults, which can actually get trickier than you'd think: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding . And when you are multiplying/dividing/exponentiating they can actually add up to quite large differences.

Is there a way to use the Excel Rounding in SQL

Rounding, and similarly precision truncation, is a rabbit hole you can go deep down. And you always have to be wary of whether what you are seeing is a ghost in the display preferences or an actual difference in the values. SQL Server seems to truncate/round to the highest level of precision in the formula, explicit casting can get around this a bit. See https://dbfiddle.uk/K22oFbIy . Which matches to my Excel to 8 digits of precision and 15 significant figures.

Are you using float for the variables? I don't think you should necessarily expect a perfect match but I suspect it will be closer if you do use floating point. https://dbfiddle.uk/HXt-csvq

Adding reference to what @shawnt00 mentioned: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/77664/how-does-sql-server-determine-precision-scale
